# PHP if statement disregarding variable check

Tags: php, if-statement

My if statement keeps looking over one of my variables and looks at the or statements and returns true. I hate describing coding before showing it...

```
if($relLoc[1] <= "32" AND $map['locationpadding'] == "0px 0px -32px 0px" OR $map['locationpadding'] == "0px 0px -32px -32px" OR $map['locationpadding'] == "0px -32px -32px 0px")
{
    die();
}
```

So if I am at `$map['locationpadding'] == "0px 0px -32px -32px"` and the 
`$relLoc[1] == "380"` the `die();` still executes.

But if I am at `0px 0px -32px 0px` It wont execute till I am at the `32` location.

Comment: To my knowledge you can't say OR, you have to say ||

Comment: In PHP OR and || is admited

Comment: I originally tried that, researched it on w3 and tried that route. Still same thing. The "OR" should be fine.

Comment: Never mind, you guys win. Thanks!

But why would this one fail. 

if($relLoc[0] <= "32" && $map['locationpadding'] == "0px 0px -32px -32px" || $map['locationpadding'] == "0px 0px 0px -32px" || $map['locationpadding'] == "-32px 0px 0px -32px"){
   die();
  }

Comment: See my post to explain why that fails.

Comment: This is more commonly known as De Morgan's laws or truth tables as you may have heard them referred to.

Comment: @Ajezior check the answers... both explain why that happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not correctly grouped the logic statements.  I do not know PHP so the syntax may be off but you essentially want this:

```
if($relLoc[1] <= "32"  AND **(** $map['locationpadding'] == "0px 0px -32px 0px" OR $map['locationpadding'] == "0px 0px -32px -32px" OR $map['locationpadding'] == "0px -32px -32px 0px"**)** ){
            die();
        }
```

Notice the additional parenthesis to denoted the correct group of boolean statements. What you have done in your original post is this:

```
if relLoc == 32 AND  $map['locationpadding'] == "0px 0px -32px 0px

  +  
OR $map['locationpadding'] == "0px 0px -32px -32px"   
  + 
OR $map['locationpadding'] == "0px -32px -32px 0px
```

So in the sample you provided it would be this:

```
$map['locationpadding'] == "0px 0px -32px -32px" and the $relLoc[1] == "380"
```

which is:

```
   False + True + False = True
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the help. All for parenthesis! Works great now!

Comment: @Ajezior great, common courtesy is to upvote / accept if this is the correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want:

```
if($relLoc[1] <= "32" AND ($map['locationpadding'] == "0px 0px -32px 0px" OR $map['locationpadding'] == "0px 0px -32px -32px" OR $map['locationpadding'] == "0px -32px -32px 0px")){
//                        ^ added                                                                                                                                                ^ added
```

Use parenthesis to separate sub conditions, otherwise your first condition becomes less relevant because after that you have OR x OR x OR x, so only one of the ORs has to evauluate to true for the whole condition to evaluate to true.